# Type conversion of declarative client URI argument

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I am implementing a **declarative client** in Micronaut that looks like this:

```
@Get("/dostuff{?requestObject*}")
fun getStuff(requestObject: MyRequestObject): String
```

My MyRequestObject contains an enum that is represented by some string:

```
data class MyRequestObject(val myEnum: MyEnum)

enum class MyEnum(val stringRep: String) {
  AREASONABLENAME("someSillyString");
}
```

When I now send a request via the client the value from `requestObject` generates the following query `/?myEnum=AREASONABLENAME`. What I actually need is `/?myEnum=someSillyString`.

I tried the following things without any success:

1. add JsonValue function to MyEnum: 
   `@JsonValue fun getJsonValue() = stringRep` - of course did not help
2. implement a `TypeConverter` for MyEnum

   ```
   @Singleton
   class MyEnumTypeConverter : TypeConverter<MyEnum, String> {
       override fun convert(`object`: MyEnum?, targetType: Class<String>?, context: ConversionContext?): Optional<String> {
           return Optional.ofNullable(`object`?.stringRep)
       }
   }
   ```

Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `toString` method in the Enum so that when the converter tries to convert it to a string you can control the result of the operation:

```
enum class MyEnum(val stringRep: String) {
  AREASONABLENAME("someSillyString");

  override fun toString(): String {
    return stringRep
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked fine :) but I have another question. My data class MyRequestObject  also has javax.validation in place. In the class body I have a method isValid which returns a boolean and is annotated with @AssertTrue which works fine. When I now call my client it also sends a value "valid=true/false". Is there a way to ignore/exclude that field?

Comment: I recommend you create a new question with that. It would be easier for everyone to see it and help you fix it. That way you can provide code examples and get more exposure. I will look it when I have time either way

Comment: Good suggestion, I created a new one, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967185/ignore-property-for-type-conversion-of-declarative-client-uri-argument. Thank you :)